# tracking issues between two properties

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up Google Analytics account with two properties:

www.example.com
buy.example.com

Now I've created a custom dimension to be used as unique user ID (I am using cookie to assign unique ID to each website visitor)

1. Does it possible to generate report for my custom dimension cross domain? (so I can see ID data from www.example.com and buy.example.com in the same repot?)
2. when I've two properties can I set a goal between them?

Thanks
Shai

Answer (score 0):

You need to only have one web property that you use on both sub-domains (www and buy).

Put the same tracking code on each.

You can then create two views, with a filter for www and buy sub-domains if you want to see them separately.

Your unique visitor counts etc. will all be cross sub-domain as you desire, and you can set Goals etc. according.